# Good practice to declare database variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Most of the times when I working with database related object I work like this:

```
// Declare a private static variable of my database
private static BlueBerry_MTGEntities mDb = new BlueBerry_MTGEntities();
```

Then, in any method (example):

```
public StoreInfo GetStoreByID(int _storeID)
{
    using (mDb = new BlueBerry_MTGEntities())
    {
        mDb.Database.Connection.Open();

        // Bla bla stuff to return the proper StoreInfo Object.
    }
}
```

Is is good practice to work this way to avoid pooling crashes and to develop an efficient MVC Asp.Net application? If not, what would be the good practices, and how would you do it?

Comment: You are create a new static instance of mDb at class level and then again creating another new instance of mDb inside the function. I dont see any point for creating class level instance. Surely it's a waste of an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing it like that - this is a misuse of the `static` feature.

The problem with your approach is that the `mDb` is visible from everywhere, at any time during the lifetime of your `StoreInfo` class, but it is valid only at the time the `using` block is executing. Once your program exist the `using` block, your `mDb` variable becomes invalid, but it remains non-null, so there is no obvious way of checking its validity. Therefore, anyone using this variable outside the `using` block runs the risk of accessing a disposed object, and triggering an exception.

Make `mDb` a regular local variable, and make sure that its scope is limited to the `using` block, like this:

```
using (var mDb = new BlueBerry_MTGEntities())
{
    mDb.Database.Connection.Open();

    // Bla bla stuff to return the proper StoreInfo Object.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to instantiate it *(or even declare it)* if you are going to use it inside `using` statement.

```
public StoreInfo GetStoreByID(int _storeID)
{
    using (BlueBerry_MTGEntities mDb = new BlueBerry_MTGEntities())
    {
        mDb.Database.Connection.Open();

        // Bla bla stuff to return the proper StoreInfo Object.
    }
}
```

If you are going to use `mDb` outside of using statement then you can just declare it but you don't have to instantiate it *(with new keyword)*.